# Json parse by search id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file like below:

`{ "userdata": { "userid123": {"uname": " john", "uemail": "john@mail.com"}, "userid124": {"uname": "sam", "uemail": "sam@mail.com"} }`

I want to parser user details if someone go to url http://example.com/?userid123

So only details of userid123 (which is in the url, get it from there) will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json string you added to the question is wrong.

If you need to get the string after the question mark and test if the corresponding value exist or not, you can write:

```js
var js = {
    "userdata": {
        "userid123": {"uname": " john", "uemail": "john@mail.com"},
        "userid124": {"uname": "sam", "uemail": "sam@mail.com"}
    }
};

var sp = window.location.search.substr(1);

//for testing purposes
sp='userid123';

if (js.userdata[sp] !== undefined) {
    console.log('uname: ' + js.userdata[sp].uname  + ' uemail: ' + js.userdata[sp].uemail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to save userId to variable like

```
var userId = location.search.substr(1);
```

`.substr(1)` <- this will remove `?` from result of `location.search();`

Now since you are using jquery you can access your json (and user data) as below

```
$.getJSON( "users.json", function( data ) {
   var userData = data[userId]; // your user data
}
```